# Is the "Windows-Defender-Hardening" safe to perform?

Tags: windows, firewalls

I'm totally not a Microsoft Windows professional. When it comes to Windows, I'm just a normal user. And as this user, I'm wondering why Microsoft isn't shipping a full potential Windows Defender by default. According to a few Blogs and IT-News, there is space to improve the using/behaviour of Windows Defender. By a Google-search, I ended on this Repository: https://github.com/simeononsecurity/Windows-Defender-Hardening

My question is to all the Windows-PowerUsers and Experts: Makes the script sense? I mean, I cannot download an executable from some Repo on GitHub and run it with root privileges. So, I'm wondering if any of you know more about the effects and the benefit of it.

Comment: I had a quick look. It doesn't look like maware or a scam (don't take that as certain). I think the issue with it is that it will break some applications, by locking down functionality they need. So it makes sense for a power user who's prepared to fiddle with it when things break, but it's not something MS would ship by default.

Comment: Typically "full potential" will break things in a lot of environments. There is a trade off between security, easy of use, and reliability. When you increase security, the other two decrease.

Comment: What's "a full potential"? Most AVs are reactive, not preemptive and mostly useless anyways. Keep your web browser up to day, install uBlock Origin, don't download random files from the web willy-nilly and you should be safe. If you're being targeted of three-letter agencies and special hacking groups, you're SoL anyways. Using Linux could be safer in this case. Linux offers security through obscurity because each distro is slightly different thus targeting a particular user is a LOT harder than targeting an average Windows/MacOS user whose software stack is the same.

Comment: We can't review and audit every arbitrary file/script for safety.

Comment: I highly suggest using this instead, No 3rd party tools used, doesn't do unofficial stuff like "debloat" or weird stuff like that. It doesn't have any pre-compiled binary so doesn't require blindly trusting it, everything is in plain text: https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security